# Question about doing in-place updates in Basho Riak

Tags: mongodb, analytics, riak

Currently I use Mongodb for recording statistics and adserving. I log raw impressions to a log collection, and processes' do findandmodify to pull off the log and aggregate into a precomputed collection using upsert (similar to how rainbird works with twitter).
http://techcrunch.com/2011/02/04/twitter-rainbird/

I aggregate on the parent, child, childs child etc, which makes querying for statistics fast and painless.

I use (in mongo) a key consisting of the {Item_id, Hour} and upsert to that (alot)

I was wondering if Riak had a strong way to solve the same problem, and how I would implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I don't think Riak supports `upsert`-like operations.

Long answer: Riak is a Key-Value store which treats stored values as opaque data. But in the future Riak could consider adding support for HTTP PATCH which might allow one to support operations similar to upsert. There is another category of operations (compare-and-set) which would also be interesting, but supporting these is definitely much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The way this works with Riak depends on the storage backend that you're using for Riak.

[Bitcask](http://downloads.basho.com/papers/bitcask-intro.pdf), the current default storage backend, uses a log-structured hash tree for the internal storage mechanism. When you write a new record to Riak, an entirely new copy of your data is stored on disk. Eventually, compaction of the bitcask will occur and the old copies of your data will be removed from the bitcask file.

Any `put` into Riak is effectively an upsert - if the data doesn't exist, a new record will be inserted. Otherwise, the existing value will be updated by expiring the old value and making the newest value the current value.